# Sort rails hash based on array of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have an array like this:

```
['one','three','two','four']
```

I have a array of hash like this:

```
[{'three' => {..some data here..} }, {'two' => {..some data here..} }, {:total => some_total }] # etc...
```

I want to sort the array of hashes by the first array.  I know I can do:

```
array_of_hashes.sort_by{|k,v| k.to_s} to sort them and it will sort by the key
```

( and the .to_s to convert :total to a string )

How can I make this happen?

Edit:

I was incorrect about how this is setup, it is actually like this:

```
{'one' => {:total => 1, :some_other_value => 5}, 'two' => {:total => 2, :some_other_value => 3} }
```

If I need to put this in a new question, just let me know and I will do that.

Thank you

Comment: what Ruby version do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

similar to ctcherry answer, but using sort_by.

```
sort_arr = ['one','three','two','four']
hash_arr = [{'three' => {..some data here..} }, {'two' => {..some data here..} }]

hash_arr.sort_by { |h| sort_arr.index(h.keys.first) }
```

Comment: I got this to work with your solution with a modification:  .sort_by{ |k,v| k = 'z' unless sort_list.include?(k); sort_list.index(k)}.  I am sure there is a better way, but I don't know it.  also I added 'z' to the sort_arr to give it a place stuff that wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

The `index` method of Array is your friend in this case:

```
sort_list = ['one','three','two','four']

data_list = [{'three' => { :test => 3 } }, {'two' => { :test => 2 } },  {'one' => { :test => 1 } },  {'four' => { :test => 4 } }]

puts data_list.sort { |a,b|
 sort_list.index(a.keys.first) <=> sort_list.index(b.keys.first)
}.inspect
```

Resulting in, the same order as the source array:

```
[{"one"=>{:test=>1}}, {"three"=>{:test=>3}}, {"two"=>{:test=>2}}, {"four"=>{:test=>4}}]
```